# Django delete user from userprofile

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django project where users can decide to delete their account and everything we know about them (solved riddles, votes ...).
I think you can compress this code but I don't know how.

I have a User related to `Comment`, `Report`, `Vote`, .... And I've got a `Userprofile` with a user relation:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Benutzer", unique=True, primary_key=True, default=None)
    # Some other fields
```

Comment-User relation:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, verbose_name="Kommentierender")
```

Report, Vote, UserClicked, UserVoted, SolvedRiddle have the same relation like `Comment`.

Article-User relation:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Autor", blank=True, default=None)
```

that's my **del** method in userprofile to delete everything from a user:

```
def __del__(self):
    user = self.User
    if user is None:
        return False
    Comment.objects.filter(User=user).delete()
    Report.objects.filter(User=user).delete()
    Vote.objects.filter(User=user).delete()

    userclicked = UserClicked.objects.filter(User=user)
    if userclicked.exists():
        for object in userclicked:
            del object

    uservoted = UserVoted.objects.filter(User=user)
    if uservoted.exists():
        for object in uservoted:
            del object

    author_article = Article.objects.filter(authors__in=[user, ])
    if author_article.exists():
        for object in author_article:
            object.remove_author(user)

    solvedriddle_user = SolvedSolution.objects.filter(User=user)
    if solvedriddle_user.exists():
        for object in solvedriddle_user:
            del object

    self.User.delete()
    self.delete()
    return True
```

Comment: Also did you test this code? I mean, did you manage to create `Comment`s, `Report`s, etc. that are lasting in the DB between manual testing sessions?

Comment: It's a method of my userprofile model. I'll test it after I've compressed it.

Comment: And if you didn't test the code, then it is not ready for review. How would you know if it work as expected?

Comment: I tested it. I had to change `del object` to `obj.__del__()`. After that it worked. Do you know how to compress this code? I think you can compress `for object in *` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not how deleting objects work in Django**.

The `__del__` method is a Python mechanism and is called when an object is garbage collected. This would be a huge mess if database rows were dropped anytime an object goes out of scope. This is also why calling `del object` doesn't seem to have any side effect: Django still caches the value somewhere, you just got rid of your variable.

Instead, you should use the `delete()` method on a model instance or on a queryset. But in fact none of this code is required as the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` will take care of that for you: as soon as a `User` object is deleted, the other linked objects will be deleted as well.

The only thing missing is to automatically delete the `User` instance when a `UserProfile` instance is deleted. This is better implemented [using signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-delete) as it will be called for both usages discussed earlier.

Alternatively, you can provide a method on your `UserProfile` model that will delete the underlying `User` and, thus, everything related to it:

```
def delete_user(self):
    self.User.delete()
```

But you won't be able to use it for bulk deletions.